# Sequelize: using build to update a record

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Let's say I have the following simple model:

```
var Foo = sequelize.define('Foo', {
    bar: Sequelize.STRING,
});
```

And the table `Foos` in the database has a record:

```
id   bar
---  ---
1    abc
```

In order to update this record I could do the following:

```
Foo.findById(1).then(function(foo) {
    foo.bar = 'xyz';
    foo.save();
});
```

Now I have found another way to update the record without having to find it form the database:

```
var foo = Foo.build({ id: 1, bar: 'xyz' });
foo.isNewRecord = false;  // makes save use UPDATE instead of INSERT INTO
foo.save();
```

This is perfect for my use case, but I'm wondering if I'm breaking anything in sequelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parameter in the `build` function that takes an object called `options`. `options` has an attribute `isNewRecord` that defaults to true. If you set this to false and use `update()` it will update the existing record after you set the primary key.

```
let instance = await db.Model.build({}, {isNewRecord: false});
const result = await instance.update({
    id: instanceId,
    column : newValue
});
```

[source](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-build)

Comment: So manually changing the `isNewRecord` value is supported by sequelize?

Comment: 'isNewRecord' is a property of the 'build()' parameter. You're not changing anything. Yes this is supported by sequelize