# Sequelize build() and update instead of query and update/bulk update

Tags: sequelize.js

Is it possible to build an instance of a record, set the primary key/ update attributes and update the instance?

Example:

```
exports.updateModel = async (event, context) => {
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    const errors = validate(body, updateSchema).errors;
    if (errors && errors.length > 0) {
        return error(httpCodes.badRequest, 'Invalid Request');
    }

    let model = db.Model.build();

    const result = await model.update({
        id : body.modelId,
        column : body.newValue
    });

    return ok({model : result});
}
```

However when I do this I get an error about a foreign key being null. The existing record already has this set, and I am not overriding it with this update call.

> "errorMessage":"null value in column \"foreign_id\" violates not-null constraint"

I know I can bulk update, and query for a single record and update, but I am curious if it's possible to build a generic model, set the id, and update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after researching/playing around a bit.

There is a parameter in the `build` function that takes an object called `options`. `options` has an attribute `isNewRecord` that defaults to true. If you set this to false and use `update()` it will update the existing record after you set the primary key.

```
let instance = await db.Model.build({}, {isNewRecord: false});
const result = await instance.update({
    id: instanceId,
    column : newValue
});
```

[source](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-build)

Also looks like [this question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286833/sequelize-using-build-to-update-a-record/55408748#55408748) a few years ago with no answer